# Wrong semaphor in case of opencl usage

Tags: memory, visual-studio-2013, opencl, mutex, nvidia

**Solution:**

Finally I could solve or at least to find a good workaround for my problem.
This kind of semaphore doesn't work in case of NVIDIA.
I think [this](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/7058-Kernels-and-mutexes?p=23902&viewfull=1#post23902) comment is right.

So I decided to use **atomic_add()** which is mandatory part of the OpenCL 1.1.
I have a **resultBuffer** array and **resultBufferSize** global variable and the last one is set to zero.

When I have results (my result is always!! x numbers) than I simple call
**position = atomic_add(resultBufferSize, x);**
and I can be sure no one writes between position and position + x into the buffer.

Don't forget the global variable must be volatile.

When the threads run into endless loops the resource is not available and therefore the -5 error code during the buffer reading.

**Update:**

When I read back:

```
oclErr |= clEnqueueReadBuffer(cqCommandQueue, cm_inputNodesArraySizes, CL_TRUE, 0, lastMapCounter*sizeof(cl_uint), (void*)&inputNodesArraySizes, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The value of the lastMapCounter changes. It's strange because in the ocl code I do nothing and I take care of sizes: what I wrote into the buffer creation and what I copy I read the same back. And a hidden bufferoverflow can cause many stange things indeed.

**End of update**

I did the following code and there is a bug in it. I want a semaphore to change the resultBufferSize global variable (now I just want to try it how it works) and get back a big number (it is supposed that each worker write something). But I get always 3 or sometimes errors. There is no logic how the compiler works.

```
__kernel void findCircles(__global uint *inputNodesArray, __global 
       uint*inputNodesArraySizes, uint lastMapCounter,
       __global uint *resultBuffer,
       __global uint *resultBufferSize, volatile __global uint *sem)
{
      for(;atom_xchg(sem, 1) > 0;)
      (*resultBufferSize) = (*resultBufferSize) + 3;
      atom_xchg(sem, 0);
}
```

I got -48 during the kernel execution and sometimes it's OK and I got -5 when I want to read back the buffer (the size buffer).

Do you have any idea where I can find the bug?

NVIDIA opencl 1.1 which is used.

Of course on the host I configure everything well:

```
uint32 resultBufferSize = 0;
uint32 sem;

cl_mem cmresultBufferSize = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
sizeof(uint32), NULL, &ciErrNum);
cl_mem cmsem = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(uint32), NULL, 
&ciErrNum);

ciErrNum = clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cmresultBufferSize);
ciErrNum = clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cmsem);

ciErrNum |= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cqCommandQueue, ckKernel, 1, NULL,
&szGlobalWorkSize, &szLocalWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);

ciErrNum = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cqCommandQueue, cmresultBufferSize, CL_TRUE, 0, 
sizeof(uint32), (void*)&resultBufferSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

(in case of this code the kernel is OK and the last reading is return -5)

Comment: Are you initializing the `cmsem` buffer with a zero value? If not, it looks like you would have an infinite loop there.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have come to a conclusion on this, but I want to point out two things:
1) The semaphore is non-portable because it isn't SIMD safe, as pointed out in the linked thread.
2) The memory model is not strong enough to give a meaning to the code. The update of the result buffer could move out of the critical section - nothing in the model says otherwise. At the very least you'd need fences, but the language around fences in the 1.x specs is also fairly weak. You'd need an OpenCL 2.0 implementation to be confident that this aspect is safe.